# How to switch the storyboard (Main or Auth) according to the user's login status

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, signing

As mentioned in the title, I have a question about how to change the first screen shown to the user depending on whether the user is already registered for an account or not.

---

I'm developing an iOS application with login functionality.
I'm developing an iOS application with login functionality. (I am using AWS Amplify / AWS Cognito for this feature.) (I have already completed the user sign up and sign in process.)

We are currently creating two storyboards.
I have implemented user authentication to unregistered users in "Auth.storyboard" and I am. On the other hand, I'm trying to provide a memo feature for registered users in the "Main.storyboard".

[image]

[image]

In order to determine whether a user is registered or not, and to branch the screen accordingly, I  wrote the following code in the "AppDelegate.swft".

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let ud = UserDefaults.standard
        let isLogin = ud.bool(forKey: "LoginStatus")

        if isLogin == true {
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
            let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home")
            self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
            self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else {
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Authentcation", bundle: Bundle.main)
            let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "auth")
            self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
            self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }


     //ellipsis........

        return true
    }
```

I use the UserDefault feature to get whether or not the user is already logged in, and then branch the screen by I think I've made the specification to do this. **However, even though I'm not logged in, the "Main. storyboard" opens first, even though I'm not logged in.**

Why is that?
I'd like to know what the solution is.
Also, if there is a better way to do this, I would like to know how to do it.

**[addition]**

Is it because you have selected "Main" in the testProject→General→Main Interface?

Comment: Have you tried to delete 'Main' in General > Main Interface? Pretty sure that should do it.

Comment: I deleted it, but the "Main" storyboard was displayed and failed.

Comment: Try to remove the "initial storyboard/viewcontroller" property from all your storyboards

Comment: It was successful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help, could you accept my answer so we can close this question?

Answer (score 1):

Delete 'Main' in YourProject > General > Main Interface and make sure to untick all 'Initial ViewController' properties if you have any in your StoryBoard's.